# Cognito standard attribute website not searchable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In the Cognito dashboard, there is a list of standard attributes that we are given to choose from:
[image]

and in the docs, it says:

> "You can only search for standard attributes. Custom attributes are
>   not searchable. This is because only indexed attributes are
>   searchable, and custom attributes cannot be indexed."

and when calling the API for `ListUsers`, `filter`ing on "website", what I thought was a standard attribute, I get the following:

> Cannot list users on the provided selector: website = "mywebsite.com"

Are these attributes not *standard enough* for this API call? or is my input just poorly formed?

Answer (score 3):

Standard attributes are the only ones that can be searched, but not all are indexed (searchable). The complete list is available here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-manage-user-accounts.html

Comment: If I need to service a cognito user, looking them up by their website, must I keep a duplicate DB in dynamo with extra indexes to do that?

Comment: I think that the only architecture that makes sense is to have a duplicate users table in dynamo and relegate searching to that.  You can use the Post-confirmation trigger to write the value to dynamo.

Comment: That is disappointing. Last year, I rolled my own auth system and user database with node and dynamodb. Then I eventually switched to cognito because it was so similar. Now that I am aware of this limitation and that i'd need to keep a copy-db of everything in order to look up customers (by an important field pertaining to the product i'm building), it makes me wonder if my own version of this was more appropriate.